# API Endpoint Semantics

Tags: api-design

Is an API endpoint the 'method', like https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/ or the full URL including non-query-string parameters like  https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/5104

In other words, are these two separate endpoints or considered the same endpoint?
http://myapi.com/somemodel/1
http://myapi.com/somemodel/2

Answer (score 61, accepted):

According to [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Services_Description_Language#Objects_in_WSDL_1.1_.2F_WSDL_2.0), the endpoint is a web service, defined by a WSDL file, and

> does nothing more than define the
>   address or connection point to a web
>   service. It is typically represented
>   by a simple HTTP URL string.

Microsoft [uses the term `endpoint` in various contexts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181835(v=VS.90).aspx), but they all amount to the same thing: the endpoint is the *entire interface,* not one particular method.

In the context of a [REST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_State_Transfer) endpoint, the endpoint would contain the requisite GET, PUT, POST and DELETE methods (as applicable).

Comment: So then http://myapi.com/mymethod/1 are http://myapi.com/mymethod/2 are both the same endpoint?

Comment: Yes, provided the 1 and 2 are parameters to your methods, and not addresses to separate, complete endpoint interfaces in their own right (possible, but not the way I would design it).

Comment: actually based on that wikipedia definition, each url leads to a service providing data for the resource described by 1 and 2.  So they are 2 differend endpoints.  I think an endpoint should be a suffix only, and they can share the same base url.

Comment: @HukeLau_DABA: Have a look also at the way the Wikipedia article defines an "operation."